# load data infile with unknown system variable error

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile, date-conversion

I´ve been trying to use load data infile procedure to load data from a csv file to mysql, althougt I'ven been unable to due it because of a unknown variable error in the set statement.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\Bets\\BD\\tables\\match.csv' 
INTO TABLE `bets`.`match` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(`idMatch`, `idChampionship`, @date, `homeTeam`, `awayTeam`, `homeTeamGoals`, `awayTeamGoals`, `matchType` );

SET matchDate = STR_TO_DATE(@date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The date field to import is in format 2011-08-07.

when running the query the error given is: SQL Error (1193): Unknown system variable 'matchDate'.

any help would be pappreciated... thanks!

Comment: it worked but,why do I need to use the @ before the column name?! never seen reference to that in mysql documentation.

Comment: read about 'user variables' as opposed to 'system variables'

Comment: if you read MySQL Load Data Infile documentation carefully, the documentation mentioned about that. This link goes there http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

When `SET matchDate` it should be like this:

```
SET matchDate = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

instead of `SET matchDate = STR_TO_DATE(@date, 'YYYY-mm-dd');`

Example of MySQL **STR_TO_DATE** function you can read [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/).

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the same issue. The SET line must be part of the LOAD DATA INFILE ... statement. In your code, the column expression is terminated by a semicolon, which executes the SET command after the LOAD DATA INFILE finishes. The user variables created in the statement are not existing any more after the statement completes. Correct statement would be as follows,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\Bets\\BD\\tables\\match.csv' 
INTO TABLE `bets`.`match` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(`idMatch`, `idChampionship`, @date, `homeTeam`, 
 `awayTeam`,`homeTeamGoals`, `awayTeamGoals`, `matchType`)
SET matchDate = STR_TO_DATE(@date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```